# Gas service in android studio logcat

Tags: android, service, logcat

I am getting an error in android studio logcat which keeps on repeating itself but I have no idea where it is coming from

`1539  1547 E GED     : Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
1539  1547 E GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
1539  1547 E GED     : Failed to execute ioctl 3222824709, BridgeID(5), err(-1)
1539  1547 E GasService: Error on query GED info, err=1
1060  1161 E ApplockRunningService.TAG: AppLockService------------->tasks = [android.app.ActivityManager$RunningTaskInfo@40598b4]
1060  1161 E ApplockRunningService.TAG: AppLockService------------->packname = com.android.launcher3
1060  1161 E ApplockRunningService.TAG: getLockFlag------------> c = android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner@a210cdd`

Answer (score 0):

This is not your fault nor your problem. This is your phone's launcher app message. Look at `com.android.launcher3`

Comment: Thanks but can you please elaborate?

Actually I am new at this and have just started learning android studio and java.

For one of my early projects I needed to create a 'button' which gives a response in logcat when pressed or tapped but for some reason this error is occuring repeatedly and there is no response in logcat when I am pressing the 'button'.

Comment: Logcat will show you all (or almost all) applications' messages installed on your phone. If you want to see only your app logs, you can add filter, like this: [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiBgcaD7-XfAhUjqIsKHWn2C2wQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F27593428%2Fhow-to-find-filter-logcat-configuration-in-android-studio-1-0&psig=AOvVaw3xQGCTW9sjmH7VHfXvphTH&ust=1547300860109806)